# cors issue with passport.js google oauth strategy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I have a setup as such:

```
-backend
    -model
        --User.js
    -routes
        --auth.js
    -database
        --connection.js
    -passport
        --passport.js
    --server.js
-client
     -react folders / files
     ...
```

In my server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const passport = require("passport");

const { authRoutes } = require("./routes/auth");

require("./model/User");
require("./services/passport");
require("./services/mongoConnect");

const app = express();

app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: "30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000",
        keys: "MY-KEY",
    })
);
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: true,
        methods: "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT",
        allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Authorization",
    })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use("/", authRoutes);

app.listen(PORT);
```

Inside my auth.js file inside my router

```
const passport = require("passport");
const router = require("express").Router();

router.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        scope: ["profile", "email"],
    })
);

router.get("/auth/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google"));

router.get("/api/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.send(req.user);
});

router.get("/api/current_user", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
});

module.exports = {
    authRoutes: router,
};
```

Inside passport.js file I have

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const User = mongoose.model("users");

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: "MY-ID",
            clientSecret: "MY-SECRET",
            callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
            proxy: true,
        },
        (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id }).then((existingUser) => {
                if (existingUser) {
                    done(null, existingUser);
                } else {
                    new User({
                        googleId: profile.id,
                    })
                        .save()
                        .then((newUser) => {
                            done(null, newUser);
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then((user) => {
        done(null, user);
    });
});
```

My frontend consists of a button that hits my auth/google route. However it logs a cors issue error in the console.

```
(redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Doea anyone know how i can solve this? In mu google console I have the redirect url setup as 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback'

Comment: when do you see the error? and is it from frontend or backend?

Comment: Frontend. When i click to login, the error presents itself in the console. I can make an request to a separate endpoint.I'm just recieving the error trying to hit the google oauth endpoint

Comment: it looks you should enable CORS in your backend

Answer (score 1):

First you need to update the cors origin with '*' or your client specific whitelisted url. But that alone is not going to solve the problem.
your button should load the auth url on the browser instead of making an api call to the auth/google route. So you can make the button a href link instead.

Comment: But if you have a link you'll get an undefined origin in the cors handler. How would you solve that situation then?

Comment: @MarcelN. That would indicate that you made a mistake somewhere. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69428848/16298054) for a step by step guide with detailed explanation.

Comment: I didn't. When you have a link it redirects you to the servers route to initiate the passport OAuth flow. When using cors without any middleware before that, I get an undefined origin. I can even test this when I want to directly access that route in the browser without clicking a link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't configure cors policy in your backend.

The most simple way is to install `cors` package if you use `Express`.

```sh
npm install cors
```

And use it as a middleware of your express app.

```js
var app = express()
var cors = require('cors');
...
app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is even though you have used cors package you have not added the following **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** option in cors. Try this :

```
app.use(
cors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT",
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Authorization",
   })
);
```

Or as yash has mentioned simply use:

```
app.use(cors())
```

[For more reference check the official npm cors documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Answer (score 0):

You have misconfigured CORS on your backend.

First, you are using wrong syntax when it comes to `methods` - there should be no spaces when you are listing them (I don't know how they are parsing the string but you should probably stick with the documentation -
according to documentation, you can specify methods either as a string: `'GET,PUT,POST'` or a list: `['GET', 'PUT', 'POST']`.

Second, you are missing `OPTIONS` HTTP method in the `methods` which is used by browsers in preflight request to test server's CORS configuration.

Third, are you sure about the specified headers?

The easiest option is to drop the CORS `options` configuration completely if you are not sure what you are doing and apply the cors globally before every request.

```
app.use(cors());
```

Or to only specific path where you want to allow CORS.

```
app.get("/somepath", cors(), (req, res) => {...
```