# CORS error while implementing google Oauth2 (MERN)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, passport.js

I have implemented local as well as google login using passport.js in a mern web application. The local authentication is working fine with the frontend but I am getting errors when using the Google strategy.

**Error**:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?.........' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/auth/google') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Error**: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

**Issue shown by the console**:  
Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site context by specifying its SameSite attribute.
Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute

I tested the google strategy using POSTMAN and it was working fine but when requesting from my frontend there seems to be some issue.

server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express=require("express");
const cors=require("cors");
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const session=require("express-session");
const passport=require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const errorController=require("./controllers/errorController")


const app=express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000", // <-- location of the react app were connecting to
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());



app.use(session({
    secret:process.env.SECRET,
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false,
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const User=require("./models/user.model");
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });


passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/google/keeper"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify:false, useCreateIndex:true});


const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});


const loginRouter=require("./routes/login");
const registerRouter=require("./routes/register");
const logoutRouter=require("./routes/logout");
const authRouter=require("./routes/auth");



app.use("/login", loginRouter);
app.use("/register", registerRouter);
app.use("/logout", logoutRouter);
app.use("/auth/google", authRouter);

app.use(errorController);

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("server started on port 5000");
});
```

auth.js (handles the google login related routes)

```
const router=require("express").Router();
const passport=require("passport");


router.get("/", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] }));

router.get("/keeper", 
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect("/");
  });

  module.exports=router;
```

Axios request from the frontend

```
function googleLogin(event){
      Axios({
        method: "GET",
        withCredentials: true,
        url: "http://localhost:5000/auth/google",
      })
      .then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      })
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```

button that triggers the request

```
<button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={googleLogin}>Sign in with Google</button>
```

Comment: Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin value to * or your FE url . Then it will work.

Comment: @AmaranadhMeda I have added origin value in cors middleware as the frontend URL. Please have a look at the server.js file. I cant mark it as * because I have withCredentials as true in my axios requests. I am stuck on this issue since 3 days :'(

Comment: Add cors configuration just before /login route configuratio.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't make an axios call to the /auth/google URL!!** 
Here's my solution...

```
// step 1:
// onClick handler function of the button should use window.open instead 
// of axios or fetch
const googleLogin = () => window.open("http://[server:port]/auth/google", "_self")

//step 2: 
// on the server's redirect route add this successRedirect object with correct url. 
// Remember! it's your clients root url!!! 
router.get(
    '/google/redirect', 
    passport.authenticate('google',{
        successRedirect: "[your CLIENT root url/ example: http://localhost:3000]"
    })
)

// step 3:
// create a new server route that will send back the user info when called after the authentication 
// is completed. you can use a custom authenticate middleware to make sure that user has indeed 
// been authenticated
router.get('/getUser',authenticated, (req, res)=> res.send(req.user))

// here is an example of a custom authenticate express middleware 
const authenticated = (req,res,next)=>{
    const customError = new Error('you are not logged in');
    customError.statusCode = 401;
    (!req.user) ? next(customError) : next()
}
// step 4: 
// on your client's app.js component make the axios or fetch call to get the user from the 
// route that you have just created. This bit could be done many different ways... your call.
const [user, setUser] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://[server:port]/getUser',{withCredentials : true})
    .then(response => response.data && setUser(response.data) )
},[])
```

**Explanation....** 
**step 1**  will load your servers auth url on your browser and make the auth request.
**step 2**  then reload the client url on the browser when the authentication is
complete.
**step 3** makes an api endpoint available to collect user info to update the react state 
**step 4**  makes a call to the endpoint, fetches data and updates the users state.